# Gas Flow and Tube Diameter

Tags: flow, gas

I have a rate of gas flow in $\frac{\text{litres}}{\text{second}}$. I am trying to find a relation between the diameter of a tube and the gas flow through this tube.

Does anyone know of such a relation?

Comment: Read up Darcy-Weisbach equation and Moody's chart. For a given pressure drop across the tube of fixed length, flow rate can change with tube diameter due to changing resistance to flow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between flow rate and tube diameter. If you make the tube bigger then the flow speed will decrease but the flow rate will remain unchanged.